# Creating a simple MVC - not sure about validation implementation

Tags: php, validation, model-view-controller

I'm creating a simple MVC app to learn more about MVC.
I have a controller which uses a UserService class to get the desired users:

```
class UserController extends Controller{
   public function Index(){
      $data['users'] = UserService::getAll();
      $this->view->render($data);
   }

   public function Add(){
      UserService::insert($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);
   }
}
```

The UserService class uses an ORM (idiorm) to get the data:

```
class UserService{
   public static function getAll(){
      return Model::factory('User')->find_many();
   }

   public static function insert($username,$password){
      $user = Model::factory('User')->create();
      $user->username = $username;
      $user->password = $password; //no good practice in real life offcourse...
      return $user->save();
   }
}
```

How do I fit in some validation in here? Like checking if the values aren't empty, that the password matches a certain validation pattern, ...

Should I do something like:

//controller

```
public function Add(){
   if(UserValidationService::checkPassword($_POST['password'])){
      UserService::insert($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);
   }else{
      //set some errordata and show the view
   }
}
```

Or should I do the validation in the service (model) and return errors?

I'm a little confused on how to put the validation right.

**Code update**

```
class UserController extends Controller{
   public function Add(){
      $result = UserService::insert($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);
      if($result[0]){
         //result ok, show view
      }else{
         //result not ok, pass errors to view
      }
   }
}

class UserService{
   $errors = "";
   public static function insert($username,$password){
      if(empty($username)){
         $errors .= "Please enter a username.";
      }
      if(empty($password)){
         $errors .= "Please enter a password.";
      }
      if(empty($errors)){
         $user = Model::factory('User')->create();
         $user->username = $username;
         $user->password = $password; //no good practice in real life offcourse...
         $user->save();
         return array(true,$user);
      }else{
         return array(false,$errors);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Validation should be done in the [Domain Object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) (which is part of the model layer) where all the business rules live. The Controller brings Domain Objects, [Data Mappers](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) (typically from Factories), [Services](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) and Views together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation for this kind of constraints should be a model-based validation. This is because you cannot rely on the thing a single model will be used by a single controller.

Your model for registering a user might be used from 5 different pages, relying on 5 different controllers. Or even by a third party. It will be an overkill to make validations in each controller. You need just to handle the return value of the model.

In your mode you can have

```
if(empty($param)) {
   return array(false, self::EMPTY_PARAM);
}
if(strlen($param)<self::MINIMUM_LENGTH) {
   return array(false, self::MINIMUM_LENGTH_NOT_REACHED);
}
```

so in your controller you are checking:

```
   if(!$model_response[0]) {
      return json_encode(array('success' => 0, 'error_msg' => 'Error message, or the constant value from the model, or something else to get proper error message'));
   }
```

You can simplify by only returning false, the example I added is to handle different errors, so you can send proper string/json to the view.

```
/* $model_response here is the return value of the model
 * I did not used associative array returning so
 * if the model return the one I said, the first key (`0`)
 * will be false. So we are checking if the first key is false
 * then testing the second key (`1`) what is its return value
 * in order to handle the error (it's mostly a pseudo code)
 */
if(!$model_response[0]) {
    switch($model_respose[1]):
        case UserModel::EMPTY_PARAM:
            $error_msg = 'Username or password cannot be empty';
        break;
        case UserModel::MINIMUM_LENGTH_NOT_REACHED:
            $errpr_msg = 'Username and password should be at least' . UserModel::MIN_LENGTH . 'characters long';
        break;
     endswitch;
     return json_encode(array('success' => 0, 'error_msg' => $error_msg));
}
```

So you just set the constraints by the model (EMPTY_PARAM, MIN_LENGTH, etc...) and handle them by the controller. You can decide to not handle some of them. The model will return false anyway, but the end user will not see the proper message.

Thus, if a third party uses your model, i.e. you have partnerships and they have gate and use your model to bring you registrations, and they forgot to tell the user that the min length is 6 characters, they still will be unable to insert into your app usernames with less than 6 chars, but their users won't see why their registration is not done.

Comment: Ok, but what if I want to return multiple errors? And what if I want to return a user object on successful save (to use the userID that has been generated)? I updated with new code at the bottom based on your feedback, is this good practice?

Comment: @randomizer I see several problems in your code. First of all, unlike Java/C# in PHP you don't have this explicit type binding. `string $var = ''` is invalid. However, I would not rely on this if a strying is empty to continue working. Once a constraint is reached stop executing the method with `return`. The real error message should be generated from the controller. You can tell the controller a hint what it may be like `const EMPTY_USER = 'empty_user'` and then if the controller see you are returning `self::EMPTY_USER`, to tell the user `Please enter a username.`

Comment: Also returning the object is good, if you really need the created object :) It's they way you did it. In your case on successful try, `$model_response[1]` will be the user object

Comment: @randomizer If you are in doubt why the model should not return the end-user error message - it's because you are breaking the single responsibility principle. E.g. your partner might want to return different error, then if he wants to manipulate, he needs to check `if($model_response[1] == 'Please enter a username'));` so he needs a whole string or sentence for comparison. And if you want to return this for translate i.e. compare a tag to the db, you will need to do it in the controller. If you do it in the model, it's too much logic in a model. One needs only to register, not to translate

Comment: I was to quick, coding c# at the moment, I corrected the code :).
I understand what you want to say with the single responsibility principle.
But I don't really understand the return on the first reached constraint. What if I want to inform the user with two warnings? For example "The username has invalid characterd" and "The provided password does not meet requirements."

Comment: Nested conditions is the one I get in mind this quickly, maybe there's a better one, but you test first if user is empty, if it is - test if pass is empty - if it is - return `user_pass_empty`, else return `user_empty`, else (user not empty too) -> continue to the next condition or execute the script: `if(empty($user)){if(empty($pass)) { return array(false, 'user_pass_empty'); } else { return array(false, 'user_empty'); }`

Comment: One more question about the constants usage. If I understand it correctly you just define them in your model/serviceclass as variables? And without a value? So const EMPTY_PARAM; const WRONG_PASSWORD, ... which you can call from the controller.

Comment: You can call constants between classes. `ClassName::CONSTANT_NAME`, in your case from the controller you can call both `UserService::EMPTY_PARAM` and `UserService::WRONG_PASSWORD`. And I define them in my model/service as constants, not variables, and with value. Which in most of the cases is meaningless. :) `const WRONG_PASSWORD = 'wrong_pass';` is constant declaration.

Comment: `const WRONG_PASSWORD = 'wrong_pass'` actually has value. While you are returning `self::WRONG_PASSWORD` and testing in controller `if($return == model::WRONG_PASSWORD)` you don't really matter what the value is. But for example, if you log the attempts to register in the DB and under the column reason you do `INSERT INTO log (reason) VALUES (self::WRONG_PASSWORD);` you will actually insert into the table the string `wrong_pass` so later you can check `if($row['reason'] == model::WRONG_PASSWORD)`.

Comment: If you change the value of the constant later on i.e. `'pass_wrong'`, your `if($return == model::WRONG_PASSWORD)` will be ok, but your `if($row['reason'] == model::WRONG_PASSWORD)` will not be ok, because you will be checking if `wrong_pass = pass_wrong`. That's why it's important they to be constants with real constant value :)

Comment: Thx for clearing that out, didn't got the point of giving them a value in your model but now I do.